# Google BigQuery Unique Visitor Conversion Rate Using Purchase Event

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

As it says in the subject line I'm trying to work out the unique visitor conversion rate using the purchases event.

This is what I have, does it look right?

Many thanks for any help

```
SELECT  
  SUM(purchase_event) / COUNT(unique_visitors) AS user_conversion_rate
FROM (
    SELECT 
      COUNT(DISTINCT fullvisitorId) AS unique_visitors,
      COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(fullvisitorId, CAST(visitId AS string), date)) AS session_count,
      COUNT(*),
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY fullvisitorId ) as n,
      COUNT(h.eventInfo.eventCategory) AS purchase_event
     FROM `xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.ga_sessions_*` as ga,
     UNNEST(Hits) as h
     WHERE _table_suffix between '20200601' and '20200630'
    AND h.eventInfo.eventCategory = 'Purchase' 
    GROUP BY fullVisitorId ,h.eventInfo.eventCategory
)
```

The code ran fine but the conversion looked a bit small.

Comment: Hi - if you look at the data you have, is your code returning the correct conversion rate? If it is then your code is correct. As no-one apart from you knows what data you’re using, what result you are trying to achieve and what result you are actually achieving, it’s impossible for anyone to help you - unless you provide a lot more information e.g. a minimal reproducible example

Comment: What is the definition of "conversion rate"? Do you have record of every visitor and then also each visitor that purchased something? (if you do then the where clause `AND h.eventInfo.eventCategory = 'Purchase' ` is a problem).

Comment: Thanks both. I think it might be the data that is the issue